# Can 2 arrays be merged into an array of structures with 2 fields using only LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I am wondering if two int arrays can theoretically be merged into a single array of structures using only LINQ, where each array going into its respective field?

So let's say we have 2 int arrays called `numbers_raw` and `categories_raw`, and `class Record` with 2 fields.

Using procedural code it looks like this:

```
class Record {
    public int number;
    public int category;
}
int[] numbers_raw =    { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 14, -4 };
int[] categories_raw = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2,  2,  2 };
var records = new List<Record>();
for (int ii = 0; ii < numbers_raw.Length; ii++) {
    records.Add(new Record { number = numbers_raw[ii], category = categories_raw[ii] });
}
```

And if we had only 1 array and 1 field we could do it like this:

```
var records = numbers_raw.Select(x => new Record { number = x });
```

But I am not sure how to do it in such a way that both arrays are used, `categories_raw` going into the `category` field and `numbers_raw` goes into `number` field.

I am not sure if it is at all possible using LINQ.

Comment: Did you attempt to use [Enumerable.Zip()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=net-5.0) ?

Comment: I didn't know about it. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Enumerable.Zip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=net-5.0) is what you need:

```
List<Record> records = numbers_raw
    .Zip(categories_raw, (n, c) => new Record { number = n, category = c})
    .ToList();
```

If one of both collections is larger, `Zip` takes all items until the common maximum count. For example, if one sequence has three elements and the other one has four, the result sequence will have only three elements.

> This makes me wonder if there is a generic solution for any number of
> arrays but I assume there isn't.

You're right, there is no `ZipAll` and it's not easy to build one. If you have 3 or 4 you could still use `Zip`, just concatenate them:

```
List<Record> records = numbers_raw
    .Zip(categories_raw, (first, second) => (first, second))
    .Zip(thirdSeq, (both, third) => new Record { number = both.first, category = both.second, thirdProperty = third})
    .ToList();
```

or provide an extension method (this exists already with C#6 but only for 3):

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<TResult> Zip<TFirst, TSecond, TThird, TResult>(
        this IEnumerable<TFirst> first, 
        IEnumerable<TSecond> second, 
        IEnumerable<TThird> third, 
        Func<TFirst, TSecond, 
        TThird, TResult> resultSelector)
    {
        using (IEnumerator<TFirst> e1 = first.GetEnumerator())
        using (IEnumerator<TSecond> e2 = second.GetEnumerator())
        using (IEnumerator<TThird> e3 = third.GetEnumerator())
            while (e1.MoveNext() && e2.MoveNext() && e3.MoveNext())
                yield return resultSelector(e1.Current, e2.Current, e3.Current);
    }
}
```

But these approches work just for a couple of sequences.

Comment: Thank you. This makes me wonder if there is a generic solution for any number of arrays but I assume there isn't. Also this action of unifying separate "channels" of information into fields of a single array must have a name but I couldn't figure out what it is so I used the word "merge".

Comment: @sashoalm: No, there is no easy or available generic solution to make `Zip` work with any number of collections. But look at my answer, i have edited it to provide a different way.

Comment: @sashoalm Side note: With .NET 6 will be possible to do Zip with 3 collections. For more, you still would have to create your own method.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use [`Zip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=net-5.0):

```
var records = numbers_raw.Zip(
        categories_raw, 
        (x, y) => new Record {number = x, category = y})
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use another version of [`.Select(element, index)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_Select__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Int32___1__)

```
var records = numbers_raw.Select((x, index) => 
           new Record { 
              number = numbers_raw[index], 
              category= categories_raw[index]
           }).ToList();
```

**Note:** Here `.Zip()` is appropriate than `.Select()` version, I just shared alternate way to `.Zip()`

---

Why I said `.Zip()` is better than `Select()`here?

- As @TimSchmelter said in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67788961/6299857), *`Zip()` takes all items until the common maximum count,* but `Select(element, index)` will work only in case of `numbers_raw.Count() > categories_raw.Count()`. It will throw an `Array out of bound` exception if this condition failed.
- If you desperate to use this solution, then always apply `.Select()` on the list which contains maximum elements.

Answer (score 1):

#### Update:

I didn't know `Zip` actually comes with the same implementation, so I reworked the extension method slightly. As I got the problem with regular `Select` that it knows nothing about the index, so we can actually workaround this with the following extension:

```cs
public static IEnumerable<TResult> SelectByIndex<T1, TResult>(this IEnumerable<T1> sequence, Func<int, TResult> selector)
{
    var baseArray = sequence.ToArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < baseArray.Length; i++)
    {
        TResult result;
        try
        {
            result = selector(i);
        }
        catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
        {
            yield break;
        }

        yield return result;
    }
}
```

And then use it like this:

```cs
var result = numbers_int.SelectByIndex(i => new Record {number = numbers_int[i], category = categories_raw[i]});
```

---

#### Old answer:

While `Zip` is good for the simple solution, you can write your own with the LINQ extension methods.

Let's assume your record class has different types of fields:

```cs
class Record
{
    public int number;
    public string category;
}
```

Then you can define your own LINQ expression for such case:

```cs
public static class LinqExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<TResult> Merge<T1, T2, TResult>(this IEnumerable<T1> sequence, IEnumerable<T2> other, Func<T1, T2, TResult> selector)
    {
        using var sequenceEnumerator = sequence.GetEnumerator();
        using var otherEnumerator = other.GetEnumerator();
        while (sequenceEnumerator.MoveNext() && otherEnumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            yield return selector(sequenceEnumerator.Current, otherEnumerator.Current);
        }
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
int[] numbers_int = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 14, -4 };
string[] categories_str = { "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2"};

var result = numbers_int.Merge(categories_str, (i, s) => new Record {number = i, category = s});
```

This will give you the flexibility of defining your own generic methods for any situtation.

Comment: Which is basically the [implementation of `Enumerable.Zip`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,3ae08ae036c4ab24). Of course you can extend it to take three sequences or four, but not any number of collections.

Comment: Thanks, @TimSchmelter didn't know that, updated the answer. Hopefully, someone might find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] numbers_raw =    { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 14, -4 };
int[] categories_raw = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2,  2,  2 };

var records = numbers_raw.Select(delegate(int value, int index)
{
      return new Record() {category = categories_raw[index], number = numbers_raw[index]};
});
```